# How do i render a template by retrieving data from db by ajax in vue js 2.0?

Tags: vue.js

i dont really understand how im supposed to trigger the rendering to begin only after the ajax call has retrieved the data from the db
Here is my script file:

```
 var _this = this;

var Child = {
  template: `<div class="row" v-for="item in alldata">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ item.code }}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
}
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    message: 'Hello a new Vue.js mesage! from App.vue',
    errors: "",
    maincode: "",
    alldata: [],
    }
  },
  mounted:function(){
         this.readall()
  },
  components: {
      'basic-view': Basic,
      'list-view'   : Child,
  },
  methods: {
    savecode: function(){
     axios.post('http://localhost/kode/code/insertcode', { 
     mcode:this.maincode })
      .then(function(response){
   });
      },
      readall: function(){
          axios.post('http://localhost/kode/code/showall')
  .then(function(response){
    _this.alldata = response.data;
  });

 }
}
```

}

this is my first project im really new to this!! Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might just be the underscore in front of _this (fourth last line). You need to do your `var _this = this` at the start of each function in your methods.

Comment: i need to use _this as the 'this' reference changes in axios. i can set the data variable from the ajax call but the output doesnt render. i need to know how do i trigger the re-rendering?

Comment: No problem! Pleased to help. Custom now requires that you accept my answer by clicking the grey tick on the left hand side. Cheers.